# Выводит слова не в правильном порядке

Tags: java

```
public void defineLanguages(String words) {
    String[] listWords = words.split(" ");

    mapOfLanguages.entrySet().forEach(list -> {
        list.getValue().entrySet().forEach(line -> {
            for (String myWord : listWords) {
                if (line.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(myWord)) {
                    System.out.print(line.getValue() + " ");
                }
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса. не могли бы добавить ожидаемое и реальное поведение в вопрос, нажав на кнопку править?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы проходите по картам в порядке следования записей в них, а нужно следовать по порядку слов в предложении. Можно сделать, например, так:

```
mapOfLanguages.forEach(
    (key, map) ->
        System.out.println(
            Stream.of(words.split(" "))
                .map(word -> map.getOrDefault(word, word))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
        )
);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо,всё работает

Comment: @SashaBushansky тогда примите ответ, если не сложно :)